# ERROR EN EL SELECTOR $ y & DENTRO DE MI .CSS

Tags: html, css, selectores-css

estaría teniendo un problema el cual consiste en que quise probar algo que encontré por internet y al momento de implementarlo en mi css no me reconoce un par de selectores los cuales son: $ y &. Necesito si alguien me podría decir en que estaría fallando por favor, a continuación les dejo una imagen:   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es sintaxis de [sass/scss](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass)

Comment: @aloMalbarez y como hago para que me funcione?

Comment: lo compilas a css https://sass-lang.com/install

Comment: @FranCirone anexo te recomiendo este otro enlace para conocer mas sobre los selectores CSS  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_CSS

Answer (score 0):

en ese caso quieres utilizar $ par declarar una variable. en css lo declaras asi:
--itemGrow: 1.2;
y para utilizarlo: var(--itemGrow)
Además estas utilizando sintaxis de sass si quieres acceder a los section que estan dentro de .wrapper tienes que hacer:

```
.wrapper section{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}
```

y si quieres acceder a los .item que estan dentro de los section dentro de los .wrapper haces:

```
    .wrapper section .item{
(tus estilos)
    }
```